# Storing sensitive data in HttpContext.Current

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, session, session-cookies, httpcontext

ASP.NET MVC Web application where I am wanting to hold on some sensitive information (an account number) while the user navigates from page to page.  I currently am using FormsAuthentication and storing it in a custom IPrinciple.  I've encrypted the session cookie and set it to be HttpOnly (can't be accessed via client-script only).  This seems like a good and secure solution to me.

However, I've been told we probably want zero sensitive information in a cookie for any reason.  So an alternative I'm considering is storing the sensitive information in HttpContext.Current.Items.  This would require the user to re-log in for each request but that's ok in this case.  They should never come to the site directly, but through links from other sites (which posts authentication information, so the user never manually logs in).

Is there any reason not to use HttpContext.Current for this purpose?

Comment: There is no reason why you couldn't use the HttpContext.Current.Items for sensitive data, but have you looked at using the session store instead? It persists the data for the whole session, instead of flushing it after the first request (as in the case with HttpContext.Current.Items) and it is more conventional practice. Just a mention

Comment: by session store are you referring to HttpContext.Session?

Comment: Yes that is correct.